# jQuery - Using :contains for instant search with nested divs/classes?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, contains

I have a search box. I'm using jQuery and keyup to filter repeating divs.

Each div looks like this:

```
<div class="searchCell" id="searchCell' . $id . '">';
    <div class="friendName">
        // someNameOutputWithPHP.
        </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to filter based on the name text. If someNameOutputWithPHP contains the search query, the entire searchCell should show(). If it doesn't, the entire searchCell should hide().

This doesn't work, though:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
        var searchValue = $(this).val();
        if(searchValue === "") {
            $(".searchCell").show();
            return;
        }
        $(".searchCell").hide();
        $(".searchCell > .friendName:contains(" + searchValue + ")").show();
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

---

---

**EDIT**

New problem: I got the divs show() to show how I want. But the :contains isn't working exactly right.

For instance: say one of the name's is Ryan. When I search for 'Ryan', I get nothing. But when I search for 'yan' I get the Ryan div.

**What's wrong?**

Here's the :contains code:

```
        $(".friendName:contains(" + searchValue + ")").parent().show();
```

Comment: Side note: `keyup` probably isn't the event you want. It only fires on key up, as opposed to key repeat (e.g., pressing and holding a key). You might use `keypress`, but that won't catch people backspacing, or pasting into the field with the mouse (right-click, choose "Paste" from the menu, on most OS's). Sadly, the only *reliable* way to detect changes to the field is to poll it (just be sure to start polling on `focus` and stop on `blur` so you're not polling unnecessarily).

Comment: Okay. Now, is there some sort of wildcard I can use to correct the searching problem in my edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are hiding the .searchCell and then showing its children .friendName divs, which though get display property will not show up because parent is hidden.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchbox").keyup(function() {
        var searchValue = $(this).val();
        if(searchValue === "") {
            $(".searchCell").show();
            return;
        }
        $(".searchCell").hide();
        //$(".searchCell:has(.friendName:contains(" + searchValue + "))").show();
        // OR
         //$(".friendName:contains(" + searchValue + ")").parents(".searchCell").show();
        // OR
          $(".friendName:contains(" + searchValue + ")").parent().show(); // If .searchCell is always a direct parent
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: seems kind of inefficient to me (using `:has()` + `:contains()` pseudos in one selector). The OP should just call `.parent()` before `.show()` in his current statement and be fine.

Comment: There was typo earlier. Corrected it(commented it though) and also added other way of navigating the hierarchy.

Comment: That works, but please refer to the EDIT I made. It's still not filtering correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector

```
$(".searchCell > .friendName:contains(" + searchValue + ")")
```

will select all `.friendName` divs that contain the text from `searchValue`. That works just fine, but you need to `.show()` the parent element. Just invoke the `.parent()` method for that:

```
    $(".searchCell > .friendName:contains(" + searchValue + ")").parent().show();
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/d3ays/3/

And by the way, you HTML markup looks messed up too. There is a `;` behind your `div.searchCell` for instance.